# Storing data for trees and graphs?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph, tree

In most tree or graph problems i tried to solve,the input is generally the entire tree or graph structure in a node1->leafs or node1->adjacent nodes format.

Is there any list of commonly used structures to save this data in memory which later helps for the intended algorithm.For example:

```
Say i have a list of graph nodes like:

1 3 8 2 4.....# 1 is connected to 3 8 2 4...nodes 
2 5 1 3...    # 2 is connected to 5 1 3...nodes
3 1 2... #likewise
. ...
8 ......
```

so if i want to use the random contraction algorithm (in which i will have to contract edges say i contract 1 and 8..i use a multi-linked list structure in which each node on the adjacency list points to its corresponding row i.e.8 in the first line points to the 8th node.

Now the question,why i chose this structure to store data?

contracting is effectively making 1 and 8 one single entity,

so i read 1's adjacency list starting from 3 and go to 3rds adjacency list change 1 to 8 and next 8's row make 1 to 8 now go to 2's list change 1 to 8....and finally i append 1s list to 8 and remove duplicates..Yep,so finally 1 is deleted from graph after contracting 1 and 8

I want to know all the usually or rarely used structures for storing trees and graphs,if associated with algos the algo name as well?Thank You

Answer (score 2):

One common way to store graphs is to use an `n`-by-`n` matrix, where `n` is the number of vertices in the graph. If you simply wanted to store the adjacency, if `X` is the matrix, then `X[i][j] = 1` if vertex `j` is reachable from vertex `i`, and `0` otherwise. You could also store edge costs or edge capacities in this manner. The disadvantage is of course the amount of memory being used, `O(n^2)` instead of `O(n+m)` where `m` is the number of edges, but the advantage is `O(1)` lookup for every possible vertex pair.

Floyd's algorithm for solving the All Pairs Shortest Paths problem can naturally make use of such a matrix, as well as more complex sub-cubic algorithms for solving various graph paths problems that utilize faster matrix multiplication over a ring.

Comment: You said if i simply wanted to store the adjacency,are there more?

Comment: @sarat I thought I already gave other examples, but sorry if I wasn't clear. `X[i][j] = c` could mean that the edge cost from `i` to `j` is `c`, Or it could mean that 1the edge capacity from `i` to `j` is `c`. You could store whatever information you like, really.

Comment: i understood what you said,but what i was asking was structural differences.What you gave me was an adjacency matrix with its advantages of denoting edge weights with the value, what i mentioned in the example was a multi-way linked list which facilitates a dynamic deletion...I am asking are there more like these?